# Unable to ignore selected elements while comparing two XML objects using XML Unit

Tags: java, xml-parsing

While comparing two XML objects considering the following constraints : 
1)Ignore white spaces 
2)Ignore the array order 
3)ignoring some elements containing date
Please help me consider the 3rd constraint
The following is the code that I tried :

```
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(true);

    DetailedDiff diff = new DetailedDiff(XMLUnit.compareXML(expectedXML, actualXML));

    List<?> allDifferences = diff.getAllDifferences();
    if(allDifferences.size() == 0)
        System.out.println("Test Passed");
    else
        System.out.println("Test failed due to following differences: ");
    for(int differences = 0; differences < allDifferences.size(); differences++) {
        System.out.println(allDifferences.get(differences));
```

Comment: Friends I've edited the question as you advised. Please reopen the question and let me find the answer. Thanks